# Parar loop na função dentro de outra

Tags: node.js

Bom dia, estou iniciando em nodejs. Preciso fazer que uma função que é chamada dentro da outra volte para meu loop,porém estou tendo dificuldades com isso. Segua a abaixo o código que fiz. Do loop para a função teste2 e da teste2 para a teste3 e da teste3 rec

```
 var teste3 = function teste3(n){
    if (n == 2 || n == 4) {
        console.log("chego na 3")
        return;
    };
}

var teste2 = function teste2(n, callback){
    if (n == 1 || n == 5) {
        console.log("chego no 2")
    }else if (n == 2 || n == 4){
        callback(n);
    }
}
var i = 0;
var teste = function teste(){
    while(i < 10){
        teste2(i, teste3);
        console.log(i);
        i++
    }
}
teste();
```

Comment: Qual é o problema? Esse código parece estar funcionando normalmente.

Comment: O objetivo é interromper o loop se entrar no `if` do `teste3`?

Comment: Meu objetivo é voltar para o loop e continuar ele, essa questão foi apenas um exemplo, caso tivesse outro if na teste3 não para fazer                                 var teste3 = function teste3(n){
    if (n == 2 || n == 4) {
     //volta para o loop sem fazer o proximo if
        console.log("chego na 3")
        return;
    };
    if(n == 0){
  
    }
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não entendi qual é o problema do seu código, mas para parar o loop, você pode usar: `break;` ou retornar seu método com `return;`.

Comment: Agora já entendi, estou trabalhando com o node e mongodb, no caso, tenho uma fila de coisas para fazer onde vão chamando várias funções através dos callbacks. Más em alguns casos em alguma determinada função preciso voltar para meu loop que fica na função inicial.

Answer (score 4):

Se o objetivo for interromper o loop se entrar no `if` do `teste3`, não basta um `return` lá dentro daquela função. O `return` precisaria estar dentro da função `teste`, pois as funções não retornam "em cascata". Outra maneira de interromper um loop é usar `break`. Eu reescreveria seu código assim:

```js
var teste3 = function teste3(n){
    if (n == 2 || n == 4) {
        console.log("chegou na 3")
        return true;
    };
}

var teste2 = function teste2(n, callback){
    if (n == 1 || n == 5) {
        console.log("chegou no 2")
    }else if (n == 2 || n == 4){
        return callback(n);
    }
}
var i = 0;
var teste = function teste(){
    while(i < 10){
        if(teste2(i, teste3)) {
           console.log('saindo do loop');
           break; 
        }
        console.log(i);
        i++;
    }
}
teste();
```